# Join attributes by value in QGIS 3.4.3 Processing Modeler

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, attribute-joins, qgis-modeler

I want to add only a few specific columns from the join table but there is no drop down list. When selecting manually I'm able to select only 1 column when trying more than 1 I'm not getting the desired results.

I have tried writing like

1] column1, column2

2] 'column1', 'column2'

3] "column1", "column2"

4] (column1), (column2)

5] (column1, column2)

But none of them works. Please help how I can add only few selected columns

PS: the drop down option is available in join attributes by field tool when I try to use it without the processing modeler

[image]

Comment: As workaround, you can join all columns then use "Refacture fields" on resulting layer to define what columns you want to keep.

Comment: @Mat How can I use the refactor fields in the model builder? In the fields mapping box I cannot enter data till the time I have some layers loaded but before I run my model there is nothing on the canvas
If you know how this can be done please help. Thanks!

Comment: Under fields maping use add field, for all desired fields fill in column names under source expression and fieldname.

Comment: Thanks Mat by using the Refactor fields tool I was able to shed out the fields that weren't required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Separate field names with a colon, eg:

column1;column2

https://issues.qgis.org/issues/20005